# Rails range_field from 0 to -100

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slider, range, negative-number

I have a range field that, when slid right, needs to make the output "more negative" up to -100.

Here's my current code:

```
<%= f.range_field :Question1, :in => 0..-100, :step => '.1' %>
```

Obviously, using :in => -100..0 works fine, but when I switch it to 0..-100, sliding to the right goes up to 100, which is clearly wrong. I need the user to be able to slide right in order to get a more negative number. Does anyone know how to make this happen?

If this is not possible, is there a way to set up :in => 0..100 but then make the number negative before it's put into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use a `before_save` filter to negate the value before saving it, or a `before_validation` to negate it before it validates and then you could validate that the number you are getting is what you want.

Comment: This is a great solution, however, say I only need it to negate if I pass :negate => 'true' into the range field. Then would I do something like if self.negate == 'true' before I execute my make_negative fxn? How do I restrict it to only some instances?

Comment: you could have `make_negative` check `self.negate`