# Getting the value of range_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, erb

I'm trying to get the value of the `range_field_tag` and display it in the page, modifying the number as it moves along. (So it starts at value 1 and displays 1, move the slider up to 3 and the displayed value changes to 3).

```
<%= range_field_tag 'ranger', in: 1...10, step: 1 %>
```

Do I have to extract the value of this in the controller or is there a way to get that working in erb? Or will that require Javascript?

Comment: See if this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313892/rails-range-field-from-0-to-100

Comment: My question was poorly written, I need to display the number chosen on the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using JavaScript to display

```
<% # your erb %>
<%= range_field_tag 'ranger', in: 1...10, step: 1 %>
<div id='target'></div>

#JavaScript using JQuery & coffee - works in Chrome
$('#ranger').on 'input', ->
  $('#target').text($('#ranger').val())
```